# installing libg2-dev on ubuntu 10.04 lucid

Tags: libraries

I am trying to install libg2-dev on my ubuntu 10.04.
I did it from synaptic package manager and also used sudo apt-get install libg2-dev.

When I am trying to configure a source code for a software I use ./configure

This is what I am getting which is a warning because of which I cannot create PS output(graph)

WARNING: libg2.a is missing.

When i look at the configure file of my software(I want to install), this is what is written when i searched for libg2.a

```
**{ $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: result: $ac_cv_lib_g2_g2_open_vd" >&5
$as_echo "$ac_cv_lib_g2_g2_open_vd" >&6; }
if test "x$ac_cv_lib_g2_g2_open_vd" = x""yes; then :
  cat >>confdefs.h <<_ACEOF
#define HAVE_LIBG2 1
_ACEOF
  LIBS="-lg2 $LIBS"
else
  { $as_echo "$as_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: WARNING: libg2.a is missing. You can download it at http://g2.sourceforge.net/" >&5
$as_echo "$as_me: WARNING: libg2.a is missing. You can download it at http://g2.sourceforge.net/" >&2;}
fi**
```

Any help how can i fix this??

Regards

Comment: What is the output of `locate libg2.a` from your terminal?

Comment: It does not produce any output

Comment: The package manager isn't installing the dev static library files. I'd suggest you install from source. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

When installing `libg2-dev`, `libg2.a` is not created and stored on the machine. I would suggest your build the library from source. [Download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/g2/?source=typ_redirect) it from their sourceforge repo.

Comment: Hi wyas, I think I will first remove what I have installed for libg2-dev completely and then install it from the link you provided. Will bug you if I still run into installation issues.

Comment: Sure, I'm here.

Comment: Hi wyas
I went to the link and used these command
tar -xzf g2-0.72.tar.gz
cd g2-0.72/
./configure
make depend
make;make install
Permission denied occured at make install so I did sudo make install
Now how can I check whether g2 lib is installed or not and where is it, and whether libg2.a is there or not??

Comment: Yeah go inside the directory and run `./configure`, `make depend`, `make`, and ultimately `sudo make install`.

Comment: Hi, I tried to configure my source code now and it worked, still I would like to know where is my g2 lib installed

Comment: The `locate` command is your best friend.

Comment: I used locate libg2.a, but it returned nothing??

Comment: /usr/local/lib/libg2.a

Comment: Yes it is there but nothing came out when i Used locate libg2.a :(

Comment: That's strange, but maybe a reboot is required. Regardless, I'm glad you found it now.

Comment: Hi wyas,
I rebooted the system today and used locate libg2.a and it gives me the result :)
Thanks